# Spring Integration http:outbound-gateway is not getting invoked

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to Spring integration. I have a project where I am trying to invoke http gateway for testing and then implement retry functionality. Below is the error I am getting while running the code. I am using spring-retry version 1.1.1.RELEASE. If I use 1.0.0.RELEASE then there is no exception but the actual http outbound call is not executed at all.

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

    <import resource="spring-mockrunner.xml"/> 

      <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>

      <int:channel id="inputChannel">
        <int:queue  capacity="5"/>
      </int:channel>

       <int:channel id="outputChannel">
        <int:queue  capacity="5"/>
      </int:channel>


     <!--  chain, inbound message, convert msg to file -->    
     <int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" destination="inBoundQueue"  channel="inputChannel" >
            <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"></int:poller>
     </int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

      <int:transformer input-channel="inputChannel" ref="xmlMsgToCustomerPojoTransformer" output-channel="outputChannel">
      </int:transformer>

    <int:payload-type-router  input-channel="outputChannel">
      <int:mapping type="org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException" channel="errorChannel"/>
      <int:mapping type="com.spijb.domain.Customer" channel="processOutputChannel" />
    </int:payload-type-router>

    <int:recipient-list-router input-channel="processOutputChannel"> 
        <int:recipient channel="normalOutputProcessChannel" /> 
        <int:recipient channel="wsRequestChannel" /> 
    </int:recipient-list-router>

     <int:channel id="processOutputChannel">
        <int:queue  capacity="1"/>
      </int:channel>

      <int:channel id="normalOutputProcessChannel">
        <int:queue  capacity="1"/>
      </int:channel>

      <int:channel id="wsRequestChannel">
        <int:queue  capacity="1"/>
      </int:channel>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorLogger" method="logError"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="normalOutputProcessChannel" ref="customerActivator"  output-channel="nullChannel" method="handleCustomer"/>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
            <value>com.spijb.domain.Customer</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
    </bean>

   <bean id="xmlMsgToCustomerPojoTransformer" class="com.spijb.transformers.CustomerMessageTransformer">
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
   </bean>



    <bean id="customerActivator" class="com.spijb.serviceactivator.CustomerServiceActivator"/>

    <!-- 
    <bean id="systemLogger" class="com.spijb.serviceactivator.SystemLogActivator"/>
    -->

    <bean id="errorLogger" class="com.spijb.serviceactivator.ErrorLogger" />

    <!-- 
    <int:service-activator input-channel="wsRequestChannel" ref="systemLogger"  output-channel="nullChannel"/>
    -->

    <!-- 
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="simpleGateway" request-channel="wsRequestChannel"
        uri="http://ajsjkdkdlskdkdkdsss.com" reply-channel="wsResponseChannel">

        <int:poller fixed-rate="500" />

        <int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
        </int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-ws:outbound-gateway>
    -->

    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="simpleHttpGateway"
        request-channel="wsRequestChannel"
        url="http://localhost/test"
        http-method="GET"
        extract-request-payload="false"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        charset="UTF-8"
        reply-timeout="1234"
        reply-channel="wsResponseChannel">

        <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
        </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>

    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <int:channel id="wsResponseChannel"/>

    <int:service-activator ref="clientServiceActivator" method="handleServiceResult" input-channel="wsResponseChannel" />

    <bean id="clientServiceActivator" class="com.spijb.serviceactivator.ClientServiceActivator"/>


    <bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice" >
        <property name="retryTemplate">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                <property name="backOffPolicy">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.FixedBackOffPolicy">
                        <property name="backOffPeriod" value="4000" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="retryPolicy">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                        <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

  </beans>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'retryAdvice' while setting bean property 'adviceChain' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'retryAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/si-components.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'retryAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/si-components.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:292)
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:114)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1149)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 51 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check that you don't use different version for spring jars.

For example we recently fixed the transitive dependency [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3741). So, check your target classpath if the `spring-core` is the same version as `spring-beans` or `spring-context`.